# Flattening a tree in linear time using Prolog

Tags: optimization, prolog

I am trying to optimize the flattening of a tree data structure in Prolog. I was able to implement the naive solution to do an in-order traversal of the list like this:

```
naive_flatten_tree(leaf(X), [X]).
naive_flatten_tree(tree(Left, Val, Right), Flattened_Tree) :-
    naive_flatten_tree(Left, LFlat), 
    naive_flatten_tree(Right, RFlat),
    append(LFlat, [Val|RFlat], Flattened_Tree).
```

Straightforward. If it's a leaf, return it, if not recurse on the left and right subtrees. Append the left, right and root values together and you get the flattened tree. Also worth noting that leaves are explicitly stated in the definition of a tree. An example tree is Tree(leaf(2), 1, leaf(3)). So the tree looks like

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
```

I need to optimize this to run in linear time to the size of the tree. The description says that this can be done using an accumulator and an auxiliary procedure in which you pass in an empty accumulator. Also states that you build the flattening of the tree in reverse order and then reverse the list once the auxiliary procedure has completed.

Edit:

Is this what you mean? Skeleton code:

```
flatten_tree(tree(Left, Val, Right), Final):-
    flatten_tree(Tree, Flat, []).

    flatten_tree(Tree, FlatHead, FlatTail):-
```

And then from here I go one by one adding to FlatTail because that is the accumulator?

Comment: There is no need to reverse anything. Write a predicate with the meaning flatten_tree(Tree, FlatHead, FlatTail), which is initially called as flatten_tree(Tree, Flat, []).

Comment: @jschimpf Hey, new to Prolog. Hard to catch on. I made an edit. Is that what you meant or am I off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An optimized solution is:

```
%      1
%     / \
%    2   3
%   / \   \
%  4   5   6

example(tree(tree(leaf(4),2,leaf(5)),1,tree(nil,3,leaf(6)))).

flatten_tree(Tree, InOrder) :-
    flatten_tree(Tree, [], InOrder).

flatten_tree(nil, Suffix, Suffix).
flatten_tree(leaf(Val), Suffix, [Val|Suffix]).
flatten_tree(tree(Left, Val, Right), Suffix, InOrder) :-
    flatten_tree(Right, Suffix, NewSuffix),
    flatten_tree(Left, [Val|NewSuffix], InOrder).
```

Examples:

```
?- example(A), flatten_tree(A, L).
A = tree(tree(leaf(4), 2, leaf(5)), 1, tree(nil, 3, leaf(6))),
L = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6].

?- flatten_tree(nil, L).
L = [].

?- flatten_tree(leaf(1), L).
L = [1].

?- flatten_tree(tree(leaf(1),2,leaf(3)), L).
L = [1, 2, 3].

?- flatten_tree(tree(leaf(1),2,nil), L).
L = [1, 2].

?- flatten_tree(tree(nil,2,leaf(3)), L).
L = [2, 3].
```

Comment: It would be nice to also see a DCG solution. For the `Prolog` tag adding that as an another answer is acceptable and then you can get more points.

Comment: @GuyCoder Thank you for your suggestion! I'll do that!

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by GuyCoder, follows a DCG solution:

```
%      1
%     / \
%    2   3
%   / \   \
%  4   5   6

example(tree(tree(leaf(4),2,leaf(5)),1,tree(nil,3,leaf(6)))).

% inorder(+Tree, -List)

inorder(Tree, List) :-  phrase(ft(Tree), List, []).

ft(nil) --> [].
ft(leaf(V)) --> [V].
ft(tree(L,V,R)) --> ft(L), [V], ft(R).
```

Examples:

```
?- example(T), inorder(T, L).
T = tree(tree(leaf(4), 2, leaf(5)), 1, tree(nil, 3, leaf(6))),
L = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6].

?- inorder(nil, L).
L = [].

?- inorder(leaf(1), L).
L = [1].

?- inorder(tree(leaf(1),2,leaf(3)), L).
L = [1, 2, 3].

?- inorder(tree(leaf(1),2,nil), L).
L = [1, 2].

?- inorder(tree(nil,2,leaf(3)), L).
L = [2, 3].
```